# Show/Hide option in Select2 using toggle or similar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a drop-down element which I apply `.select2()`, before, when it's a common `SELECT` element I use this code to toggle a element:

```
$('#orders_nat_lives_in_ccs').click(function() {
    $(".shipping_from option[value='MRW']").toggle(!this.checked);
    $(".shipping_from option:eq(" + ((this.checked) ? 1 : 0) + ")").prop('selected', true);

    $(".secure_shipping").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

But this not work for Select2 what's the right way to do this using this library?

Here you have a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/61v9edea/1/) example around what I'm talking about, first drop-down has `.select2()` applied and code doesn't work, second one is the same but without Select2 and the same code works.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle? i'm not really following what should be happening

Comment: @JayRizzi I've updated my answer with example, take a look

Comment: I tried to achieve the same in various ways but its getting complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As select to is taking options even if they are hidden I found removing and appending the option is easier. please find the code bellow

```
$('#orders_nat_lives_in_ccs').click(function() {
    if(this.checked){
        $(".shipping_from option[value='MRW']").remove()
       $(".shipping_from").select2("val", "DOMESA");
    }else{
        $(".shipping_from").prepend('<option value="MRW">MRW - COBRO EN DESTINO</option>');
       $(".shipping_from").select2("val", "MRW");

    }
//    $(".shipping_from option[value='MRW']").toggle(!this.checked);
//    $(".shipping_from option:eq(" + ((this.checked) ? 1 : 0) + ")").prop('selected', true);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works I've updated the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/61v9edea/2/) with the solution for others.